# Django rest Framework, GDAL, 'OGRException'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, gdal

Добрых суток. Не получается апнуть django с версии 1.11 на версию 2.0 и выше, из-за ошибки, связанной с геофреймворком, которую выдаёт DRF:

```
File "D:\python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework_gis\apps.py", line 13, in ready
    from .fields import GeometryField
  File "D:\python36\lib\site-packages\rest_framework_gis\fields.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal import OGRException
ImportError: cannot import name 'OGRException'
```

В описании релиза django 2.0, написано, что исключение `OGRException` Было заменено на `GDALException`, но почему-то DRF во всех версиях пытается его импортировать.

Буду признателен за любые подсказки.

Comment: дрф тут ни при чём. это `rest_framework_gis`. Обнови его https://github.com/openwisp/django-rest-framework-gis/blob/master/rest_framework_gis/fields.py

Comment: https://github.com/openwisp/django-rest-framework-gis/commit/ecfb2f6447a79c4e1f6bfb8329de70036d64f16a#diff-dc41434392d098f7395c9d89d9a000e8

Comment: @unknown, проглядел. Спасибо, так и есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это проблема не с `DRF`, а с `rest_framework_gis`. Нужно этот пакет обновить. Начиная с этого [релиза](https://github.com/openwisp/django-rest-framework-gis/releases/tag/v0.12.0), ошибка должна исчезнуть.